# Reducing responsibilities and Collaborators for Unit Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, anti-patterns

I have a class which has a well-defined responsibility - to "Enrich" an object with the information it needs. This information is gathered from a variety of sources (Services). Eg:

```
public class Enricher
{
      private CounterpartyService counterPartyService;
      private BookingEntityService bookingEntityService;
      private ExchangeRateService exchangeRateService;
      private BrokerService brokerService;
      ... 6 more services

    public EnrichedTradeRequest enrichTrade(TradeRequest request)
    {
        EnrichedTradeRequest enrichedRequest = new EnrichedRequest(request);

        // Enrich with counterparty info
        enrichedRequest = enrichCounterParty(enrichedRequest)

        // Enrich with booking entity info
        enrichedRequest = enrichBookingEntity(enrichedRequest)

        // Enrich with exchange rate info
        ...

        // Enrich with broker info
        ...

        // ....etc
        return enrichedRequest;
    }

    private EnrichedTradeRequest enrichCounterparty(EnrichedRequest enrichedRequest)
    {
        // Get info from CounterpartyService
        // ...

        return enrichedRequest;
    }
```

The logic for "how" to enrich a request is contained here. The class could be extended for different types of trade for example.

We enrich the trade in one step because we don't want any partially-enriched objects floating around, which wouldn't make a lot of sense.

The class is really difficult to unit test, because it has so many collaborators (up to 12 other services it calls upon). I would need to mock up 12 services, each with 3 or 4 different methods.

How do I reduce the number of collaborators in this case, and make this code testable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you have too many collaborators.  If its difficult to test, then design can probably be improved.

One option is to create a facade service that manages the interaction of the collaborators.  In your case, you might have a hierarchy of facades, since having only one will just move the need to have a lot of mocks into another area, which doesn't solve the problem.  If possible, try to group services that are more likely to be used together into facades.  Or alternatively, if you always call the same X methods across services together, put that functionality in a single method somewhere. If you have a single facade which in turn calls 3-4 other facades, each test will only need 3-4 mocks which is more manageable.

The end result of this will be that your 'enricher', will only call one facade service, so testing will be easy. The trade off being the need to test your facades, which will be manageable.

Comment: This seems like a good "practical" solution - it would split the logic evenly over other classes. But it also doesn't feel quite right. All I'm doing is arbitrarily splitting the class up. In our code, the concept of these new groups don't really exist - each service is quite distinct in what it does and what it represents. It is probably the solution I'll go with however.

Comment: @djcredo, its not arbitrarily splitting the code up.  Its a design pattern that is intended to reduce this sort of complexity.  @axel has a good approach too.

Comment: I 'm not criticising your approach. I'm saying that we have not good logical groupings available to us. How we choose which services would fit into which facades would be arbitrary.

Comment: @djcredo, no i didn't take it as criticism.  Just saying that creating a facade does not arbitrarily split up the code....

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to write testable code is by practicing TDD. This helps you write testable code, because you first need to write your test before you can write any production code. I recommend you to read [Uncle Bob's three laws of TDD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd). But below I will give you a summarize of the first part:

> Over the years I have come to describe Test Driven Development in
>   terms of three simple rules. They are: You are not allowed to write
>   any production code unless it is to make a failing unit test pass. You
>   are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient to
>   fail; and compilation failures are failures. You are not allowed to
>   write any more production code than is sufficient to pass the one
>   failing unit test.
>
> You must begin by writing a unit test for the functionality that you
>   intend to write. But by rule 2, you can't write very much of that unit
>   test. As soon as the unit test code fails to compile, or fails an
>   assertion, you must stop and write production code. But by rule 3 you
>   can only write the production code that makes the test compile or
>   pass, and no more.
>
> If you think about this you will realize that you simply cannot write
>   very much code at all without compiling and executing something.
>   Indeed, this is really the point. In everything we do, whether writing
>   tests, writing production code, or refactoring, we keep the system
>   executing at all times. The time between running tests is on the order
>   of seconds, or minutes. Even 10 minutes is too long.

This [Guide: Writing Testable Code](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/) is also very interesting read and gives you a lot of tips to write testable code.

### UPDATE

### Refactoring

When you have test in place you just need to do refactoring, but keep in mind you are not allowed to write any production code, before you have a failing test. I think your (might)[class has to much responsibilities](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-class-does-too-much/) when it has up to 12 collaborators.

> Extract a class where you are altering existing behavior. As you work
>   on existing functionality, (i.e. adding another conditional) extract a
>   class pulling along that responsibility. This will start to take
>   chunks out of the legacy class, and you will be able to test each
>   chunk in isolation (using Dependency Injection).

### Working Effectively with Legacy Code

I would like to point out [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)

> **The Legacy Code Change Algorithm**
>
> When you have to make a change in a legacy code base, here is an
>   algorithm you can use.
>   1. Identify change points.
>   2. Find test points.
>   3. Break dependencies.
>   4. Write tests.
>   5. Make changes and refactor.

### Mocking frameworks

Also I would like to point that you can eliminate much of the pain mocking objects by using mocking frameworks like for example [Mockito](http://mockito.org/). I played with this one and I like this one the most.

Comment: I like this answer, and I definitely ascribe to TDD (even if I sometimes find it hard to practice it. Yet it doesn't answer the specific question I'm asking.

Comment: @Djcredo you are absolutely right about that :$ although your question is hard to answer correctly too.. I try and update my answer to give a little bit better answer(hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

Without going back to complicated design patterns: Why don't you move your "enrich" methods into the respective services? This way, you could keep the list of which steps of enrichments are processed inside your `Enricher` class but delegate the actual `enrich` calls into the services which have the knowledge to actually enrich the trade. These services can then be tested individually.

Applied to your code:

```
public class CounterpartyService {
    private EnrichedTradeRequest enrichCounterparty(EnrichedRequest enrichedRequest)
    {
        // Enrich trade with counterparty details..
        // ..
        return enrichedRequest;
    }
}

public class Enricher
{
    private CounterpartyService counterPartyService;
    // ... 6 more services

    public EnrichedTradeRequest enrichTrade(TradeRequest request)
    {
        EnrichedTradeRequest enrichedRequest = new EnrichedRequest(request);

        // Enrich with counterparty info
        enrichedRequest = counterPartyService.enrichCounterParty(enrichedRequest);

        // Enrich with other info
        //  ...

    }
}
```

Comment: A thought that has also crossed my mind. However, the logic of how to enrich trades differs by what the trade is. E.g., FX trades might have different logic to Fixed Income trades. Having the logic in the Enricher class means I can subclass it eg FXEnricher.  I don't think I'd want to subclass the counterparty service in the same way.

Comment: If you pass different lists of enrichers to your class, you can have different behaviours with no need to create new classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your undelying problem is the recent linguistic drift by which *unit testing* has come to mean *isolation testing*.

A slightly more traditional definition of unit testing comes from the phrase 'the unit of testing is the unit of release'. So if a something like your *enricher* can't be usefully discussed, specified or delivered except in terms of the services it wraps, the the same applies to its tests too.

If that gives you tests of of the form 'poke it this way, and it behaves according to the way it should', then the unit test police won't come and arrest you...

Proxy when there is a reason to: asynchronous, slow, external, multiply-implemented, or unstable services. Otherwise, a test that uses the real thing will give you better results, faster.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a chain of atomic enrichments.
2. Make each enrichment is a function in term of Guava framework.
3. Test and develop each function in isolation
4. Combine tested functions into the production code.

For start - an empty enrichment

```
final Function<EnrichedTradeRequest,EnrichedTradeRequest> ID = 
  new Function<EnrichedTradeRequest,EnrichedTradeRequest>() {
     public EnrichedTradeRequest apply(EnrichedTradeRequest arg) {
       return arg;
  }});
```

To invoke it - call Y = ID.apply(X).

Then one by one develop, test and introduce into the production each of the enrichment functions.

```
import com.google.common.base.*;

private FuEnrichCounterParty = ...;
void setFuEnrichCounterParty(...) 
private FuEnrichBookingEntity = ...
void setFuEnrichBookingEntity(...) 
...

public EnrichedTradeRequest enrichTrade(TradeRequest request)
{
    EnrichedTradeRequest enrichedRequest = new EnrichedRequest(request);
    // Enrich with counterparty info
    enrichedRequest = FuEnrichCounterParty.apply(enrichedRequest)
    // Enrich with booking entity info
    enrichedRequest = FuEnrichBookingEntity(enrichedRequest)
    // Enrich with exchange rate info
    ...
    return enrichedRequest;
```